# Automatic generation of functions following a matrix rule

Tags: python

I have a matrix **A** that defines which elements have to be used in the program.

For example, if I have the following matrix **A** and a vector **v**:

```
A = [[1,0],[1,1]]
v = [3, 4]
```

I have to define the expressions:

```
prob =+ x[0] > v[0]
prob =+ x[0] + x[1] > v[1]
```

I want to automatically generate the previous functions for a matrix that was a size of *10000 x 10000*. Is it possible to do it with python?

Comment: You want to add boolean values? Does not make sense. x[0] > v[0] will be a boolean value.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what your pattern is, but you could probably vectorize your calculation in numpy

Comment: Yes, I vectorize it and it works.